# php - Compare arrays with duplicated values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to **compare** (**without remove ANY value**) 2 arrays BUT each of these arrays can have duplicated values so for e.g. I have those 2 arrays:

```
$options = ['G', 'W'];
$selectedOptions = ['G', 'G', 'W'];
```

This should return `FALSE`. Below is my code which I have. It works good but only for unique values, how to 'upgrade' it for duplicated values?

```
$mergeOptions = array_merge($selectedOptions, $options);
$intersect = array_intersect($selectedOptions, $options);
$diff = array_diff($mergeOptions, $intersect);

if (count($diff) === 0) {
    // $options are 'equal' to $selectedOptions
} else {
    // $options are not 'equal' to $selectedOptions
}
```

More examples:

```
| selected | options | result |  
+----------+---------+--------+  
|  G, G, W |  G, W   |  FALSE |
+----------+---------+--------+
|   G, W   |  G, W   |  TRUE  |
+----------+---------+--------+
| G, P, W  | G, G, W |  FALSE |
+----------+---------+--------+
| G, P, G  | P, G, G |  TRUE  |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do with or because of these duplicates

Comment: `$options = ['G', 'W'];`, `$selectedOptions = ['P', 'G', 'W'];` is result `true` or `false` ?

Comment: @Cid It's should return `FALSE`

Comment: @RiggsFolly This not exactly duplicate because here he doesn't want to remove them but to compare even if duplication exists

Comment: Are you sure @DavidWinder ? Seems the simplest route to a solution

Comment: @RiggsFolly It may be good way to achieve that but it is not the same question - therefor I don't think its qualify as duplicate question. And notice the OP specify that he DO NOT want to remove the duplicate

Comment: @DavidWinder It does now, it did not specify any such thing when I Duped the question. I have reopened it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the arrays with [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and then compare them.

```
$a = ["P", "G", "G"];
$b = ["G", "P", "G"];
sort($a);
sort($b);

if ($a == $b) {
    echo "TRUE \n";
} else {
    echo "FALSE... \n";
}
```

Comment: Sort is a good idea, I was en route to post an answer with `array_count_values()` when Riggs closed the question